# Issues in compiling grpc python code from protos

Tags: python, grpc, proto

I am using python version 2.7.6 and grpcio version 1.12.0. I have a proto with message definition containing a enum something like this

```
enum Test {
    first 0;
    reserved 1;
    second 2;
}
```

Now when I try to compile using command

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I./ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. mydata.proto
```

I get an error message something like this

```
Missing numeric value for enum constant
```

Is it because of the python and grpcio version?

Answer (score 1):

Your message definition uses invalid syntax. Perhaps you intend something like:

```
enum Test {
    first = 0;
    reserved 1;
    second = 2;
}
```

Note the added equals signs. This enum specifies two values, `first` and `second`, and reserves "1" for future use.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw an answer on here because this was the top Stack Overflow post when I was getting the same error `Missing numeric value for enum constant` when I had `reserved` fields in an enum.

I was trying to compile the headers for C++ and downloaded [the `protoc` compiler](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases) that was linked from [the protocol buffers tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial). Running Ubuntu 18.04 and just *could not* get the thing to recognize the reserved fields.

[This Github issue](https://github.com/wechaty/grpc/issues/116) was mentioning that I needed to have version 3.6, but I just downloaded and made 3.20 and it still wasn't working.

The issue for me was that I didn't follow the documentation all the way. There is a [Readme in the protobuf repo](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/README.md) that says, in part:

> To build and install the C++ Protocol Buffer runtime and the Protocol Buffer compiler (protoc) execute the following:
>
> ```
> ./configure
> make -j$(nproc) # $(nproc) ensures it uses all cores for compilation
> make check
> sudo make install
> sudo ldconfig # refresh shared library cache.
> ```

I did the `./configure`, `make`, and `make check` steps, but then forgot to `sudo make install` or `sudo ldconfig`. Once I did that, I got the correct version when I ran `protoc --version`.

I did have an issue where I did all this, got the right version, and then still had errors, but the terminal window I was using had been opened before I installed. Once I ran `source ~/.bashrc` I was able to build the messages without any issues!